# Include object type when serializing using GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

Let's say I have a some basic types:

```
public class Base {
    String a = "a";
    Nested nested = new Nested()
}

public class Nested {
    String b = "b",
}
```

Serialising this with GSON, I get:

```
{
   "a": "a",
   "nested": {
      "b": "b"    
   }
}
```

This is all good, but what if I want to preserve the object type as well, according to the following:

```
{
    "Base":
    {
       "a": "a",
       "nested": {
           "Nested": {
               "b": "b"  
           }  
       }
    }
}
```

I could try writing a custom serializer to solve this (Just assume an equivalent one is written for Nested as well):

```
new JsonSerializer<Base>() {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Base src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
         Map<String, Base> selfMap = new HashMap<>();
         selfMap.put(src.getClass().getSimpleName(), src);
         return context.serialize(selfMap);
     }
}
```

The problem with this, however, is of course that I get stuck in an infinite recursion when serializing the base type.

Is there any other way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try in this way

```
Base base = new Base();
base.a="a";  
base.b="b";

Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonElement je = gson.toJsonTree(base);
JsonObject jo = new JsonObject();
jo.add(Base.class.getName(), je);
System.out.println(jo.toString());
```

Out put:

```
{"Base":{"a":"a","b":"b"}}
```

Edit:

for your edit in the question.

You can try with [Genson](http://code.google.com/p/genson/)

```
Base base = new Base();
base.a="a";
base.nested=new Nested();

Genson genson = new Genson.Builder().setWithClassMetadata(true).create();
String json = genson.serialize(base);
System.out.println(json.replaceAll("\"@class\":",""));
```

Out put:

```
{"Base","a":"a","nested":{"Nested","b":"b"}}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will not work if I have nested objects - only the top-level instance will get labelled. I have updated the question to bear this out.

Comment: @chrsva ok. provide your object which has nested object. Your question not giving that to me

Comment: `{
    "Base":
    {
       "a": "a",
       "nested": {
           "Nested" {
               "b": "b"  
           }  
       }
    }
}` This is not a valid `Json`. Check by your own http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: Yes, I missed a colon after "Nested", but I am sure you understood what I meant.

Comment: @chrsva Note that with Genson http://owlike.github.io/genson/, using class metadata, you will ser the class type in the object and it will also be used when deserializing back. I discourage you however to replace the key (@class) used by genson with a string.replace, not very robust...just keep it as it is, and if you want register Nested class as an alias.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera you should remove the replaceAll, and just say that people can configure the value using an alias and should let the key as is, this allows to deser back to the correct type. I think it is a bad practice to "modify" generated json by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Just subclass the gson serializer and serialize the object as normal. Once you have it, get the class name using introspection and set it as the key to a new map with the value being gson's json object.  Return this object now from your custom serialize method.

Don't override the custom serialize method, jus create a new one that uses the original serialize method.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add the class name in top of object tree. You could have something like this.

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 JsonElement je = gson.toJsonTree(new Base());
 JsonObject jo = new JsonObject();
 jo.add(Base.class.getSimpleName(), je);
```

Comment: I know, but the problem with this is that it only handles the object at the top of the tree, not nested ones. This was not borne out in my question, I will update it.